# Why does this JSoup query only work when the <i> tag is omitted?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse the wikipedia page below using JSoup, and don't know why the selector with the "i" in it returns nothing:

```
// this prints nothing:
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_American_films_of_1989").get();
Elements allFlics = document.select("ul > li > i > a");
Elements allFlics = document.select(selector);
for(int i=0; i < allFlics.size(); i++){
    Element movieLink = allFlics.get(i);
    System.out.println("Got a movie with italics in selector: " + movieLink);
}

// this prints everything:
allFlics = document.select("ul > li > a");
allFlics = document.select(selector);
for(int i=0; i < allFlics.size(); i++){
    Element movieLink = allFlics.get(i);
    System.out.println("Got a movie WITHOUT italics in selector: " + movieLink);
}
```

When the `<i>` is taken out of the selector, it returns way too much.

Comment: Why do you think that there should be any results? Which results did you expect to find an why?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll use API? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

JQuery even aan't find any elments  ul > li > i>  a

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use this as a selector instead: `"ol > li > i > a"`

You can easily try it out in your browser. Open the javascript console of that page and type: `$('ol > li > i > a')`